# Vuetify v-stepper not showing content of the all steps

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Using VueJS Vuetify 2. The content of step 2 is not showing. I'd like to use the vertical list in non-linear mode.

```
    <v-stepper vertical non-linear>
        <v-stepper-items>
            <v-stepper-step step="1" complete>
                1 Step
            </v-stepper-step>

            <v-stepper-content step="1" complete>
                This is the Step 1
            </v-stepper-content>

            <v-stepper-step step="2" complete>
                2 Step?
            </v-stepper-step>

            <v-stepper-content step="2" complete>
                This is the Step 2
            </v-stepper-content>
        </v-stepper-items>
    </v-stepper>
```

**Result** not showing `This is the Step 2`.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you attach a v-model to the v-stepper component and set this to 2?

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior. However, is not what I am looking for. This way will just show the content of the current step in usage.

Comment: On your `v-stepper-step` component add the editable attribute. This may be a bug with v-stepper because removing non-linear still allows non-linear behaviour with the editable prop on `v-stepper-step` component.

Comment: Guess it is by design, v-stepper can only show one-step content one time